# How to use Visual Studio's Error List

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Am I the only one who finds the error list in Visual Studio a little awkward to use?  Can anyone explain why it behaves the way it does?  When clicking on the Warnings tab or the Errors tab or the Messages tab you don't always get the errors, warning or messages.  Insead, the view remains as it was already.

Comment: In C++ first error in a long list of errors is often the most important, regardless of what VS might think, so I've long given up on Error List window, and just use Output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an observation you already made but the Error, Warning and Info "buttons" in the error view are **TOGGLE BUTTONS** and show/hide the respective class of output message, which when I first came across them was not what I expected and did seem rather confusing.

Now I know they toggle the display of the correspondingly captioned output type on/off I find it quite sensible.  It also behaves as expected; when you know what to expect!

Answer (score 1):

It only make sense once you learned how it works. But, still this UI could confuse a lot of people when they have seen it the first time.

The Error/Warning/Message buttons look like Tabs but work like Checkboxes. It can be very confusing if a first time user clicks on them and execpts the behavior of Tab buttons.